# ¿Cómo pasar un segundo parámetro al Adapter de un RecyclerView en Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

Estoy migrando mi código de Java a Kotlin y encuentro un problema con el Adapter de un RecyclerView.

Yo necesito cambiar el color de fondo del CardView de forma dinámica, en Java había creado el Adapter así, para poder pasarle el parámetro `bgColor` para el color de fondo:

```
public class HomeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private static int bgColor;
    private final List<HomeItem> mDataSet;

    public HomeAdapter(List<HomeItem> dataSet, int bgColor) {
        mDataSet = dataSet;
        HomeAdapter.bgColor = bgColor;
    }

    //...
}
```

Al convertirlo a Kotlin, queda así:

```
class HomeAdapter(private val mDataSet: List<HomeItem>, private var bgColor: Int) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    init {
        Companion.bgColor = bgColor
    }

    //...

    class ViewHolder(v: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v) {
        private val viewIcon: ImageView
        private val viewText: TextView
        private val relativeLayout: RelativeLayout
        private var mItem: HomeItem? = null
        init {
            val cardView = v.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.mainCardView)
            cardView.setBackgroundColor(bgColor)
            // ...
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private var bgColor = 0
    }

}
```

No entiendo mucho la conversión que hace Kotlin (apenas empiezo en este lenguaje), lo cierto es que no encuentro forma de que reconozca el parámetro que le paso a través de `bgColor`, el cual siempre es `0`. Depurando, `bgColor` tiene un valor distinto de `0` en el constructor, pero no encuentro forma de pasarlo al interior de la clase. Todo lo demás funciona bien.

El adapter lo inicializo así desde el Fragment:

```
homeAdapter= HomeAdapter(mList,adapterBgColor)
```

Comment: Duda, por qué usas una variable estática si cada instancia que crees depende de ella y también la modificará?

Comment: No acabo de entender el problema, pero  creo que si quitas la sección de `init` y el objeto acompañante y pasas a usar directamente el atributo `bgColor` se solucionará.

Comment: @Mateo lo de crearla estática es para poder usarla en `class ViewHolder`. Y curiosamente ahora funciona el código, el problema era que le estaba pasando un color transparente que no hacía el efecto esperado, cuando lo cambié al color blanco funcionó. O sea, no era el código en sí mismo, sino el parámetro que le estaba pasando.

Comment: Ah. Deberías probar jetpack compose. Permite programar en forma declarativa, como Flutter y React. Tiene su propia manera de hacer las cosas pero es interesante.

Comment: @Mateo sí sí, lo estuve mirando y me encantó, además se pueden hacer cosas impresionantes de forma muy sencilla. En cuanto tenga tiempo haré una migración a Jetpack Compose, cuando no me sienta tan perdido en Kotlin, pues vengo de Java. Gracias por todo. Saludos.

Comment: Si, parece difícil pero es fácil. Cualquier duda pregunta en el [chat] tal vez te pueda ayudar.

Comment: Como ya te comentaron, no es necesario crear el companion object para definir la propiedad estática `bgColor`. Si necesitas referenciar esa propiedad en tu `viewHolder`, marca la clase `ViewHolder` como `inner`.

Comment: @Marcos, ¿o sea que con `apply` puedo hacer todo lo que requiera dentro de ese bloque? Pues esa podría ser la respuesta. No lo sabía.